# Sending emails in a secure way

Tags: c#

HI I developed an application to generate a report and the generated report should    be     emailed to the address given in the config file . Andmy code sends email to outlook    only and i as in the live environment there wont be any outlook i want to send    it in general . 
   How can i achive this?

```
public void DCCEmailSetup(DateTime dateRunReport, string path, string messager)
{
    toEmailSetup = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["To mailid"];
    fromEmailSetup = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From mailid"];

    try
    {
        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(toEmailSetup);
        message.Subject = " Report generated " + dateRunReport;
        message.From = new MailAddress(fromEmailSetup);
        try
        {
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(path));
            message.Body = messager;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw ;
        }

        var smtp = new SmtpClient(" ");
        smtp.Send(message);
    }   

    catch (SmtpException ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException
          ("SmtpException has occured: " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: you may consider configuring your SmtpClient instance! See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx for further details on MSDN or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916841/send-mail-in-asp-net for a nice example on this topic.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little lost, do you mean your live environment has no access to your Exchange server?

Comment: Just a tip; don't use "throw e" in your catch block - you are losing the stack trace of the caught exception. Use "throw" instead.

Comment: Yes live environment has no exchange server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your live environment has no access to the Exchange server it will need access to a relay or something capable of forwarding messages to your Exchange/email server, otherwise no emails can be sent.  Sorry :(